# Get Azure Active Directory application users and roles

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-active-directory

I've setup an application in Azure AD Premium and made user assignment required to access the application.  I've added custom app roles to the application manifest.  I can assign users with a role to the application.

How can you get a list of all users that are assigned to the application and their assigned role?

Comment: From the portal or using code ?

Comment: I was hoping it was built into the portal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Azure portal (preview)**

In the new Azure portal, under "Enterprise applications" > (your app) > "Users and groups", you'll now see only the list of users who are assigned to the application, as well as the app role they are assigned to. You can also filter and sort by app role. Here's an example:

[image: Azure portal / Enterprise applications / Users and groups]

*Note: As of September 2016, the Azure AD management experience in the new Azure portal is in preview.*

**Classic Azure portal**

Under and application's "Users and groups" you can list all users (and what their assignment state is), as well as all groups:

[[image: Classic Azure portal / Active Directory / Application / Users and groups]]

**PowerShell**

Using the new [preview (as of Sept 2016) Azure AD PowerShell module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureADPreview), you can use the following example:

```powershell
# Get all service principals, and for each one, get all the app role assignments, 
# resolving the app role ID to it's display name. Output everything to a CSV.
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal | % {

  # Build a hash table of the service principal's app roles. The 0-Guid is
  # used in an app role assignment to indicate that the principal is assigned
  # to the default app role (or rather, no app role).
  $appRoles = @{ "$([Guid]::Empty.ToString())" = "(default)" }
  $_.AppRoles | % { $appRoles[$_.Id] = $_.DisplayName }

  # Get the app role assignments for this app, and add a field for the app role name
  Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId ($_.ObjectId) | % {
    $_ | Add-Member "AppRoleDisplayName" $appRoles[$_.Id] -Passthru
  }
} | Export-Csv "app_role_assignments.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

**Azure AD Graph API**

With Azure AD Graph API, you can do the equivalent of what the PowerShell script does, above (in fact, the new Azure AD PowerShell module uses Azure AD Graph API for the majority of the requests).

List all service principals:

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/{tenant-id}/servicePrincipals
```

List a service principal's app role assignments:

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/{tenant-id}/servicePrincipals/{object-id}/appRoleAssignments
```

Comment: I was hoping to use the portal to see a list of users and their roles.  I can see in the Classic Portal I click on "Users And Groups", but it shows me every user in the AD, not just ones assigned to my app.  And when I find a user that is assigned to my app, it just says assigned and there's no way I can tell what their app role is.  Is the only way to see a list of just users for my app and their role is to build a custom app myself using the Graph API?  Seems like something obvious that should be in Azure AD applications.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, that's the only way, currently. I think this can be expected when Azure AD is made available in the new Azure portal (https://portal.azure.com). In either case, please be sure to vote up these two feature requests, either of which would both address your request: [filter app assignment](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/10114377-assigning-users-to-applications), [show app assignment](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/11730363-in-applications-i-need-to-see-groups-and-users-ass).

Comment: @Jeremy Your votes were very quickly taken into account. :) I've edited the answer to include the new Azure AD management functionality in the new Azure portal. More details about the preview: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/09/12/the-azuread-admin-experience-in-the-new-azure-portal-is-now-in-public-preview/

Comment: Wow that was fast.  Of course I just spent the weekend building a full CLI to manage users in Azure applications.  Thanks for the update!  It's much nicer to have it all in Azure.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to get the roles using code? How does the authentication work in that case?

Comment: @Ewertonews Without using PowerShell, you would just call the Microsoft Graph API (https://graph.microsoft.io). To call the Microsoft Graph API, you need to register the client app, and then obtain an access token. More details in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-developers-guide