# Application shows as 'Microsoft Accounts' as publisher but not show up through powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

I had an app in the Azure tenant, type is 'web application' but does not have a reply URL address, nor a single sign on section available (yet it supports issue a saml token) . It also only viewable in 'enterprise application' but not get listed in 'app registrations' or through azure powershell command. It was registered by one of vendor, not sure how they did it. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Get-AzureADServicePrincipal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadserviceprincipal?view=azureadps-2.0) to get `PublisherName`.

```
$app=Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId "1d777aec-c0af-4b4a-****"
$app.PublisherName
```

Here is the result:

[image]

You also could refer to this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39356317/get-azure-active-directory-application-users-and-roles).